# Using promises in Axios requests

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying to work out the best way to achieve something.  When I land on a Profile page, the Profile component loads the data for that profile.  This is assigned to `this.profile`. Within this data is a path to a file, where I want to process some data using this file.  To me, the below approach seems slightly risky.

```
created() {
    let vm = this;

    let url = `/api/profile/${this.$route.params.id}`;
    axios.get(url).then(response => {
        this.profile = response.data;

        d3.json(response.data.fileName)
        .then(function (data) {
            //do some stuff

        }).catch(function (error) {
            // handle error
        });
    });
}
```

Instead of that, I want to ensure that I first have the data from the axios call.  So I am thinking I need a promise?  I was thinking something more along the lines off

```
created() {
    let vm = this;

    let url = `/api/profile/${this.$route.params.id}`;
    axios.get(url).then(response => {
        this.profile = response.data;
    }).then() {
        d3.json(response.data.fileName)
        .then(function (data) {
            //do some stuff

        }).catch(function (error) {
            // handle error
        });
    };
}
```

But the above is incorrect, it is mainly to show what I am trying to achieve.  I was wondering how I can maybe use deferred and promises to only execute the d3 stuff once the axios call is made.

Thanks

Comment: All the code inside the `axios.get().then()` function is only going to run once the web request has returned and `response` has been populated. I'm not sure what the problem is here? (you're also not actually using `this.profile`...)

Comment: I think d3.json() is based on callbacks and not promises. And as far I read, d3.json is to fetch something from the server and modify it as JSON. it is almost analogous to axios!! why use both ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve this by chaining promises, assuming that `d3.json` returns a promise:

```
created() {
    let vm = this;
    let url = `/api/profile/${this.$route.params.id}`;
    axios.get(url)
      .then(response => {
        this.profile = response.data
        return d3.json(response.data.fileName)
      }).then(data => {
        //do some stuff
      }).catch(err => {
        //log error
      })
}
```

Comment: `d3.json()` does return a promise: https://github.com/d3/d3-fetch/blob/master/README.md#json

Answer (score 2):

That's where `async/await` comes in handy. A you don't need to save `this` to a variable and B you have cleaner, more readable code.

```
async created() {

    const url = `/api/profile/${this.$route.params.id}`;
    const { data } = await axios.get(url); // Optional destructuring for less clutter
    this.profile = data;

    const d3Data = await d3.json(data.fileName);
    //do whatever you want

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
async created() {
let vm = this;

let url = `/api/profile/${this.$route.params.id}`;
try {
const {data} = await axios.get(url)

const d3Data = await d3.json(data.fileName)
    } catch(err) {
      //error
    }
}
```